# Transforming a list of words and their morphological segmentations in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

I have a text file with a list of words with their morphological segmentations:

for example:

> aims  aim:aim_V s:+PL, aim:aim_V s:+3SG
>
> airline   air:air_N line:line_N
>
> alarm's   alarm:alarm_N 's:+GEN
>
> alchemists    alchem:alchemy_N ist:ist_s s:+PL

I want to trasform this text file in a 2D array in Python where the first dimension is the word and the second dimension is a string representing the morphological segmentation of the word

For example for the word 'airline' the morphological segmentation should be BMEBMME where:

- B is the beginning of a morph
- M is a middle character of a morph
- E is the end of the morph

We have also the S that stands for a single-character morph, for example for 'aims' we have BMES as its morphological segmentation.

The words are already segmented into morphs on the right part of a line.

I'd really appreciate your help :)

Comment: is the morphological segmentation for 'aims' BMEB?

Comment: Sorry, I miss the S that stands for a sigle-character morph

Comment: So aims will be BMES

Comment: Hmm, interesting problem! I'll have a think.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I'm trying to work with characters before the ':' sign in the morphological segmentation on the right part of a line

Comment: When you say '2D' do you mean that a word like 'aims' would give you BMES, BMES because there are two segmentations given?

Comment: No I mean the word+ its segmentation

Comment: Can you post what you want the array to look life for 'aims' and 'airline' (or more!) in the array structure

Comment: myArray=[(aims,BMES),(airline,BMEBMME),....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = 'myfile'

fh = open(file)

segArr = []
for line in fh:
        list = line.split()

        output = '('+list[0]+','
        for word in list[1:]:
                fragments = word.split(':')
                fragment = fragments[0]
                if len(fragment) == 1:
                        output += 'S'
                else:
                        output += 'B'+'M'*(len(fragment)-2)+'E'
        segArr.append(output+')')

print (segArr)
```

Using your examples above gives:

```
['(aims,BMESBMES)', '(airline,BMEBMME)', "(alarm's,BMMMEBE)", '(alchemists,BMMMMEBMES)']
```

I doubt the handling of the apostrophe in alarm's is correct, but it's a start!

Comment: That's awesome! The apostrophe is correct as well! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! As I said, interesting problem. Thanks for accepting it.